# Does sys.modules have any specific order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Specifically, are they in order of first imported to last? Or some other order? Undefined order?

Comment: [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) is a *dictionary*, so has no guaranteed order.

Comment: This also depends on the import hooks that may be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sys.modules is a `dict`; `dict`s, being hash-tables, have undefined ordering.

See this question: [How to determine if one module has been loaded before or after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733864/how-to-determine-if-one-module-has-been-loaded-before-or-after-another)

EDIT:
As of 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. From my experiments, the order in which you import stuff does seem to match the order in which they appear in sys.modules.

Answer (score 1):

sys.modules is a dictionary, so it is unordered by default. The order in which modules are printed out is random.

```
in: type(sys.modules)
out: <type 'dict'>
```

Hope that helps!