# How to determine if one module has been loaded before or after another

Tags: python, python-3.x

The use-case for this is that a library I'm writing uses Python modules to store data that is by necessity heavily interleaved with code; each "database entry" is a subclass of a class defined in a higher module. There is also a module containing functions for searching this "database" which uses introspection to find entries based on filters given by the user, and only checks modules that have been imported already. It's usually configured to return the first result it sees.

This library will also want to interact with user-provided database modules. A user module may want to "override" an entry from another module, and I'd like the order in which the modules are checked to be well defined. Ideally, I'd like the entries to be checked from most recently imported to least recently imported.

How can I sort the contents of `sys.modules` by the order in which they were imported?

Comment: If you're depending on the order of module loading, your design is broken.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's the best way I can think of to make sure the user gets the result he most probably wants by default.

Comment: can you have the modules register themselves through a function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement rpattiso's idea as

```
data_modules = []
def reg_import(modname):
    mod __import__(modname)
    data_modules.append(mod)
    return mod
```

Then search data_modules in reverse order.  This requires that users import and use reg_imports, but it gives you a clean list of data modules to search.  A possible alternative would be something like the following before user imports.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys

od = OrderedDict()
od.update(sys.modules)
sys.modules = od
```

This would be automatic from the user's point of view, but mixes data modules in with other modules and would require more processing to separate them.  I would go with the registration function.

Comment: Of course, if the registration function is called from the module being loaded, not only is the process rendered much more transparent to the user but the desired ordering can be made to occur as a natural consequence of when the modules are added to the list.

Comment: Another option, ofter used by applications (as opposed to libraries), is to require placement of plug-ins (add-ons, user configuration) in a known location.  The application itself then imports the plugins (or whatever) after importing its own defaults.

Comment: Yes, within module registration could be done by importing the registration function.  The module name in the module would have to match its filename (or at least, its import name) and the name would, at some point, have to be looked up in sys.modules to get the module itself.  What might be easiest is if the library has a function `import_overrides(path)` that users call with the path to a directory containing their override modules.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the order in which modules are imported isn't very common and this hints that this is not the right approach. Instead the library should include functionality as needed to allow the user to override certain entries.

This also fits Python's views on software development: explicit is better than implicit and everything the user wishes to override should be explicitly spelled out and communicated with the library. This may seem cumbersome but it requires the least amount of magic and is better to maintain in the long run.